# EF6 + MySql + Identity + another DBContext

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

ASP.NET MVC 5 with EF6 and MySql using Identity 2.  I've been doing DBA-like 'bigdata' for quite a few years and now I'm back in the land of code.  I understand EF as an architecture but am struggling with my lack of expertise in getting the ground floor laid for my project especially with the MySql wrinkle.

What I have done successfully:  Created a project with a MySQLConfiguration, MySqlHistoryContext, and MySqlInitializer, ran a migration to successfully create the tables for Identity, deployed the site to local server and can successfully register a user and log in.  GREAT!

Question:  I'm lost as far as how to manage two contexts, merge contexts, what ought be my best practice so I can continue to extend Identity objects and add new database tables through POCO models and migrations to the same database and have them work through a context at the controller.

Guidance would be helpful.  I believe my issues are in creating the second context which I would prefer use the same connection.

Attached are my class mods from other tutorials and references.

How do I create a new context which would create a new table from a POCO model using a migration??

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

}
```

Some comments online suggest not needing a MySqlInitializer.  I hardcoded the db name so simply "get it working".

```
public class MySqlInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            context.Database.Create();
        }
        else
        {
            var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
                string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [hardcodeddbname].__MigrationHistory"));

            if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
            {
                context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.Create();
            }
        }

    }

}




public class MySqlConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MySqlConfiguration()
    {
        SetHistoryContext(
        "MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));

    }
}





public class MySqlHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public MySqlHistoryContext(
      DbConnection existingConnection,
      string defaultSchema)
    : base(existingConnection, defaultSchema)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you wanna have Identity users and your data in same (one) database?

Comment: Yes.  I'm really striving to not be terribly complicated but I'm wrestling with the differences in sharing/combining contexts with MySql atop the mix.  I've read reference to inheriting from ApplicationDbContext or ____ and struggle in identifying the right *approach* so I sink my teeth into ironing out the right details.  Identity seems rarely mentioned outssde it's own universe.  Appreciate any feedback of help.  Veteran programmer stuck in laying the groundwork.